# How to bind JSON data to jqgrid?

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am trying to bind json formatted data to Jqgrid.This is simple website application.I have tried for customized table.Now I want to bind it by using jqgrid. 
.aspx or script Code is as follows:

```
  <script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "JQGridBindData.aspx/GetAllDetails",
                        data:{},
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(result.d);
                            var array = data.Table;
                            colNames: ['Country_Code', 'Country', 'ISD_Code']
                            colModel: [
                                {name: 'Country_Code', index: 'Country_Code', width: 60, sorttype: "int"},
                                {name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 60, sorttype: "string"},
                                {name: 'ISD_Code', index: 'ISD_Code', width: 60, sorttype: "string"}
                            ]
                                              },
                        multiselect: true,
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                        pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        viewrecords: true,       
                        caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
                        error: function (){
                            alert(JSON.stringify(Error));
                        }
                     });

                });

            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <table id="jQGridDemo">
            </table>
            <div id="jQGridDemoPager">
            </div>
        <br />
        <br />
            </form>
```

in my .cs page i am getting the values like this. my .cs side code is

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetAllDetails()
        {
      Generic gn = new Generic();
      DataSet ds = gn.ExecuteDataset("Country_master_view", 0);
      string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds,Formatting.Indented);
      return data;
        }
```